# Cancel scroll event when another key is pressed

Tags: linux, scrolling, events

When I scroll with middle mouse the event of scrolling is continued until it gradually turns to 0.

Think this is a general issue as I experienced it on more than 1 linux distro (NixOS and ArchLinux) and different desktop/window managers. Currently I'm using `i3` window tiling manager.

I'd like to stop the event on any other button press to prevent situations like:

- `Scroll + Ctrl` triggering zooming when only `Ctrl +Scroll` should
- `Scroll` in one window then switch to another window where event continues (also happens with first example)

Answer (score 0):

This happens because of `synaptics` option `CoastingSpeed`.

Setting to zero prevented it.

in configuration:
`Option "CoastingSpeed" "0"`

on command line:
`synclient CoastingSpeed=0` (this will not persist after reboot)